# How to regex filter a string on a substring threshold?

Tags: .net, regex

I'm wondering how to filter a text field based on not matching more than 2 predefined substrings.  For example, if a string contains a match to more than two of the substrings: tion sia ier iest ent then reject it.

But if I try

```
(tion|exal|ta|iest|ent){,2}
```

then it doesn't seem to match on stuff it should be like 'exalt' or 'cow', where it should match on these and not on 'exaltation'.  Case is not important.

Comment: Please specify which language/regex flavor you're using.

Comment: .NET  There is an online validator [here](http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx)

Comment: You may find http://refiddle.com of use. it is similar to regexlib except it provides the ability to store a regex along with test cases. Here's an example using @iamnotmaynard's answer: I added some test cases using refiddle - http://refiddle.com/by/jay-walker/filter-substring

Answer (score 2):

This will match the strings you want to reject (and not match those you don't):

`.*((tion|exal|ta|iest|ent).*){3}`

It worked for me in Java and Ruby. Your results may vary.

Comment: That works for me on the .NET engine tester here: [link](http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx) as well.  I wonder how to match the ones to keep out of curiosity though.

Comment: @user2027080 does it really have to be done with a single regex?

Comment: It could probably work by matching non matches, but at this point I'm curious how to take the inverse of the above expression in regex.  The logic of it seems simple enough.